# Cider: how to run a comand on startup?

Tags: clojure, boot, cider

I have a web app project that uses `boot` and `reloaded.repl`.
It has the following piece of configuration:

```
(require
<...>
 '[reloaded.repl :refer [init start stop go reset]]
<...>)
```

I start it as `boot dev`, and do a `(cider-connect <...>)` to the instance - after a while a `*cider-repl <stuff>*` buffer appears.

The first command I want to run and always run is `(go)` in the Repl so that the dev server is ready.  How can I configure Cider to invoke a command when the connection is ready?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation and searching for "cider startup", "cider run command when repl is ready" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined with the idea of Rulle's answer, this works:

```
(add-hook 'cider-connected-hook (lambda ()
                                  (cider-interactive-eval "(go)")))
```

When evaluated in the *scratch* buffer, the `(cider-interactive-eval "(go)")` unhelpfully errors out with "No linked session", but when put in a hook, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how to run a command when the REPL is ready, but would it be acceptable to have a keybinding, e.g. `Ctrl + F12`, in Emacs for running the command? If that is an acceptable solution, you could have the following code in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```lisp
(defun initialize-reloaded ()
  (interactive)
  (cider-interactive-eval
   "(do (require '[reloaded.repl :refer [init start stop go reset]])
        (go))"))

(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 
          (lambda ()
            (define-key clojure-mode-map (kbd "<C-f12>") 'initialize-reloaded)))
```

In the above code, I have included the code to require `reloaded` but you can omit that if that code is already required by the source file.

Then all you have to do is to press `Ctrl + F12` to start the server.